# Angularfire2 compiling issues in Angular 5.2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

When trying to add angularfire2 to my angular latest version app and initiate it, I get the following errors. Could anyone suggest a workaround please.

**The Error is :**

```
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"D:/xampp/htdocs/tpradmin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,15): error TS2305: Module '"D:/xampp/htdocs/tpradmin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'auth'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,21): error TS2305: Module '"D:/xampp/htdocs/tpradmin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'database'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,31): error TS2305: Module '"D:/xampp/htdocs/tpradmin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'firestore'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,42): error TS2305: Module '"D:/xampp/htdocs/tpradmin/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.
```

Installed Angularfire2 with npm with --save also installed firebase. 
On Adding angularfiremodule to the appmodule i get the above error.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { FirebaseCredentials } from './firebase.credentials';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FirebaseCredentials)

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is the package json code.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tpradmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please copy the text of your error and your code, instead of supplying them as images.

Comment: It is not directly related but please consider that angular fire 2 requires rxjs in version 6. If you want to upgrade check the migration guide [Migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) . It could fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem I have updated to angular 6 and everything is working